# How to debug a Konva stage not responding to click event

Tags: javascript, konvajs

I have a Konva stage defined as the following code describes, and the stage is not responding to click, even though it is responding to drag and is automatically dragged.

Is there a way to debug the click problem??

The stage has a layer over it with some objects which don't fully cover it.

```
this.stage = new Konva.Stage({
    container: divName,
    width: this.width,
    height: this.height,
    draggable: true
 });


this.stage.on("click mousedown", function() {
    console.log("click");
});

this.stage.on("dragstart", function() {
    console.log("dragstart");
});


this.nodeLayer = new Konva.Layer();

this.stage.add(this.nodeLayer);
```

Comment: Did you see my answer? Maybe you have something else in your code that is intercepting the clicks ?

Answer (score 0):

The snippet below is built from your code. Click seems to work in this simple example. Could you post more of your code ?

```js
var divName = 'container1';
var width = 300;
var height = 200;

this.stage = new Konva.Stage({
    container: divName,
    width: width,
    height: height,
    draggable: true
 });


this.stage.on("click mousedown", function() {
    console.log("click - stage");
});

this.stage.on("dragstart", function() {
    console.log("dragstart - stage");
});


this.nodeLayer = new Konva.Layer();

this.nodeLayer.on("click mousedown", function() {
    console.log("click - layer");
});

this.nodeLayer.on("dragstart", function() {
    console.log("dragstart - layer");
});



this.stage.add(this.nodeLayer);

var layer = nodeLayer; 
$('#addshape').on('click', function(){
var rect = new Konva.Rect({ x: 10, y: 10, width: 50, height: 50, fill: 'cyan'});
layer.add(rect)
layer.draw();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/konva/2.5.1/konva.min.js"></script>
<p>Click the canvas first - note the 'click - stage' event fires but no 'click - layer'. Now add a shape and click it - note the layer click occurs before the stage click.</p> 
<button style='position: absolute; z-index: 10;' id='addshape'>Add shape</button>
<div id='container1' style="width: 300px, height: 200px; background-color: silver;"></div>
<div id='img'></div>
```

Comment: Hi, sorry but I was busy. My code is currently quite complex and it's difficult to extract a better sample. I have however simply a div containing the canvas, and indeed I have now used -as a wokaround -  the div to intercept the click. Thank you for you answer.

Comment: ok appreciate that. Looks like there is something in the construction of your DOM or canvas contents that is catching the clicks first. Without more to go on we are a bit stuck providing an answer. Sorry. If the answer clarified the situation by showing you how to debug your clicks then please mark it as correct so that other readers in the future can judge the relevance for their situations.